# fatal error: Array index out of range in swift 2

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

I have problem with array of GMSMarker. when i run my code its shows  "fatal error: Array index out of range". I am going to remove markers from google map. i don't understand why this error comes. This is simple but pls help me to catch problem.

```
var MarkerList = [GMSMarker]()

    if(MarkerList.count > 0){
        for var j = 0 ; j < MarkerList.count ; j++ {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.MarkerList[j].map = nil    
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to print a log that says exactly what is the size of your array and the current index (j) for each iteration?

Comment: remove the main queue, why are you setting it to nil on main queue.? UI related updates should be done on mainqueue

Comment: from which queue do you run your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run the whole for loop on the main thread. Or you can go even better and use the new forEach function in Swift2.

**Before:**

```
if(MarkerList.count > 0){
    for var j = 0 ; j < MarkerList.count ; j++ {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.MarkerList[j].map = nil    
        }
    }
}
```

**After:**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    MarkerList.forEach { $0.map = nil }
}
```